# Error when sending or listening, Azure ServiceBus

Tags: c#, .net, azure, servicebus

I have a client that sending and listening on a topic in Azure ServiceBus. The client is running locally on my Windows 8.1 machine. But I got following exception on SendAsync and ReceiveAsync:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: The requested Performance Counter is not a
>   custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly.

The code looks like this:

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");

            var client = SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topic, subscriptionId);

            while(true)
            {
                var message = await client.ReceiveAsync();
```

and

```
string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");

            TopicClient client =
                TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topic);

            var msgToSend = new BrokeredMessage(msg);

            await client.SendAsync(msgToSend);
```

Ang one with a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a firewall related issue.