# "The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter,.." when using Azure ServiceBus TopicClient

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, performancecounter, azure-servicebus-topics

I get the following exception message when I try to send a simple message with the `TopicClient` from the nuget package `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`:

> "The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly."

Here is my code:

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("xxx");

if(!namespaceManager.TopicExists("test"))
{
    namespaceManager.CreateTopic("test");
}

var client = TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString("xxx", "test");

var messages = data.Select(x => new BrokeredMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x))).ToArray();

await client.SendBatchAsync(messages);
```

I get the exception when calling `SendBatchAsync`.

I found this question [Error when sending or listening, Azure ServiceBus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495614/error-when-sending-or-listening-azure-servicebus), which is asking the same thing. But the resolution is not relevant for me.

I have installed this nuget package `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.PerformanceCounters` (and executed the attached cmd-file) in hope that it would solve the problem, but it is still not working.

Anyone know how to solve this?

I get the same error when I try to listen to messages on the topic with the `SubscriptionClient`. I am runnig VS as an administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I had enabled that exception in the Exception Settings window (Debug > Windows > Exception Settings)